# how to set base image in coding while adding image programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product, simple-product

I added the code to update the product images programmatically.

Please refer the below code

```
$firstProduct  = Mage::getModel ('catalog/product')                                 
                        ->load($firstProductId);

$firstProduct->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery(
                        $filePath,
                        array('image','thumbnail'),
                        false,
                        false
                    );
$firstProduct->save();

/*debug*/
$mediaGallery = $firstProduct->getMediaGallery();
print_r($mediaGallery);
```

My doubt here is, how to set added image as base image.

Thank you for your valuable inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save product base image use this,

```
if(//baseimage only one time)
{
    $mediaAttribute = array (
                'image',
                'thumbnail',
                'small_image'                  
            );
}
else
{
    $mediaAttribute = null;
}

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath_to_image, $mediaAttribute, true, false);
```

**Edited**

```
//3rd param is move, if it is true then move source file
//4th param is exclude,if true mark image as disabled in product page view
```

if you create a new product then, setting it with second attribute array as `'image','thumbnail','small_image'` automatically set as base image,
or if you edit your product,
then just save new image as base with first condition i given, it sets default base image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but no luck, i checked function with core file 3 parameter stands for moving source file. Please let me know if i am doing wrong.

Comment: What you have tried and what you get with my code.It should be used to set for only one image.Try my edited code.

Comment: I tried the same code above, images are added. But in admin base, small and thumbnail images radio buttons are not checked for that image. Regarding third parameter i set as false because i don't want to move the original image file.

Comment: @Venkat so you are editing the product right?

Comment: yes, in existing product adding new image and make this is base image.

Comment: so the previous base image should be saved as thumbnail image, so use null for that

Comment: yes you were right. Its working, it set the value to default store. I crossed checked with database and found out. Thanks for your great effort. I voted up :).

Comment: sounds good :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working for Magento 1.9

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(5000);
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $gallery_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
  $path = $gallery_images->toArray()["items"][0]["file"];
  if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
  if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($path);
  if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($path);
  $product->save();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code for assign base image for a product if not assign.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$app = Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$c = 0;
foreach($products as $p){
    $pid = $p->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);

    //get all images
    $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();

    //if($product->getImage() != "no_selection" ){   OR

    if($product->getImage()){
        continue;
    }else{
        if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
            //loop through the images
            foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){

                //set the first image as the base image
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('image'=>$image['file'],'small_image'=>$image['file'],'thumbnail'=>$image['file']), 0);

                $c++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo($c . " product(s) updated.");
?>
```